# Wordpress menu and plugin installation problem

Tags: plugins, menus, installation

Am I the only one who is getting this problem or is the problem in wordpress new version. Please someone clarify. The version is wordpress-4.2.4

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the buggy admin bar it is an issue with the latest version of Chrome. Lots of people are on version 45 and have the same issue. See this article for the full details and solution.

http://wptavern.com/a-bug-in-chrome-45-causes-wordpress-admin-menu-to-break

[image]

Comment: As for the error message it could be a matter of things that are causing it. I would check out some of these links below. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/an-unexpected-error-occurred?replies=24  https://wordpress.org/support/topic/please-helpan-unexpected-error-occurredsomething-may-be-wrong-with-wordpress?replies=10  https://wordpress.org/support/topic/an-unexpected-error-occurred-something-may-be-wrong-with-wordpressorg-or-this-11?replies=20

Comment: Thnx for the knowledge. I agree with you regards to menu. But May I know the problem about installing plugins. Why it is showing "unexpected error". Please let me know. Thnx. :)